# How to use Polars with WASM

Tags: rust, webassembly

pretty new to rust and WASM, I am looking at using Polars with WASM but am having a hard time building when using wasm-pack with a web target. I found something saying to use the lazy feature of polars so my Cargo.toml looks like:

Cargo.toml

```
polars = {version = "0.22.1", features = ["lazy"]}
```

I am getting the following error when compiling the wasm target:

```
`error[E0432]: unresolved import `sys::position`
|
51 | pub use sys::position;
|         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `position` in `cursor::sys`
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who wanted this I think the following works,
early stages but the following seems to be working.

With the 0.25.0 release.

If you add the following:

**Cargo.toml:**

- polars-core = "*"
- polars-lazy = "*"
- getrandom = { version = "*",
  features = ["js"] }

**lib.rs:**

- use polars_core::prelude::*;
- use polars_lazy::prelude::*;

Then use polars as normal it seems.

**Example Wasm Function**

```
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn test(){
    //Log column B of DF to web console

    let df = df! {
         "column_a" => &[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
         "column_b" => &["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
    }.unwrap();

    console::log_1(&df.column("column_b").unwrap().to_string().into())
}
```